# Wordpress Post href dynamic

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a newbie with wordpress and my problem is that I wanted to link to a site using a link tag. Example:

WORDPRESS POST URL = `www.defaultsite.com/my-awesome-site?name=admin`

So in my link tag it would be:

```
<a href="http://www.othersite.com/admin" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```

Wherein the name is **dynamic**. But unfortunately in wordpress **POST**, I cannot echo out $_GET['name']. How would I solve this problem?

So what I would want to achieve is:

```
<a href="http://www.othersite.com/".<?php echo $_GET['name'] target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: Probably the quickest and cleanest way of doing this would be to implement your own little shortcode, so that it can be replaced with the correct content when the post is rendered.

Comment: Hello Sir thanks for answering. I've solved it now. I've used a plugin called PHP Code for posts. Thanks a lot for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. What I did was install a plugin called [PHP Code for posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-for-posts/) and then used the shortcode on the **link tag**. Example:

```
<a href="http://www.othersite.com/[php snippet=1]" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```

Wherein **[php snippet=1]** is the shortcode. More info at [CLICK HERE.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-for-posts/installation/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://www.othersite.com/<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: This does not work. I cannot code php on POST in wordpress.

Comment: @user3233787,create a custom template and use that template in post

Comment: If you can't use a custom template then i think the best way is  creating a shortcode as suggested by CBroe

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'I cannot code php on post'? it's a bit unclear to me.

Comment: Hello Sir thanks for answering. I've solved it now. I've used a plugin called PHP Code for posts. Thanks a lot for your suggestion!

Comment: If you solved the problem, you could post the answer here for the future visitors. good luck.

Comment: @SasanJ. Hello and sorry if its unclear to you. So what I just wanted is that the link tag will be linked to other page based on the URL of the page. For example I have a page and then the URL of that page is www.defaultsite.com/my-awesome-site?name=admin, then the link tag on the content should redirect to www.othersite.com/admin.

Comment: @SasanJ. Ok will do. Thanks!